# Django: can a 'database is locked' error be caused by wrong IntegrityError handling?

Tags: django, sqlite

I end up with a locked [sqlite3](/questions/tagged/sqlite3) database always after a page which catches an [integrityerror](/questions/tagged/integrityerror) (`IntegrityError`) exception. Could the lock be caused by a wrong exception handling? And if it could be, what should be the correct handling?

Currently, I just catch the exception and print a line for a streamed view:

```
try:
    Model(pk='key').save()
    Model(pk='key').save()
except IntegrityError:               
    yield 'Already existing in the database'
```

Later, on another page, when I try a `Model.objects.all().delete()` I receive `DatabaseError: database is locked`.

This is not a performance issue, because I'm just running it on the test server, and the lock persists until I restart the server. I'm thinking about a thread locked on the database, probably because after the exception I should release some kind of resource.

Comment: Could you add the code that's raising the exception to your question? It would help track down the problem.

Comment: @bouteillebleu: It was just a double insert which raised an IntegrityError due to primary key replication. I added some explicative code within the 'try' construct in order to give an idea

Comment: Hi, Did you find a solution for this? I just stumbled upon the same problem.

Comment: @SalvatoreIovene sorry, i don't remember anymore, it's been a while since i was working on that